# How to check if a value is in between values in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list

I want to check if a value exists in between two numbers in a sorted list and print what two numbers it exists between. For example, if the list is `[1, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]` and I want to see what two numbers the number `3` is between, `1` and `4` should be printed out. Is there any way to do this in python preferably without importing a module?

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want 1, 4 even if the list is like [8, 1, 12, 4, 20, 16] right?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, the list is sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the list is sorted, you could use [bisect.bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect):

```
import bisect

lst = [1, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

i = bisect.bisect(lst, 3)
print(lst[i - 1], lst[i])
```

**Output**

```
1 4
```

**UPDATE**

Without importing a module use:

```
lst = [1, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
i = next(j for j, e in enumerate(lst) if e >= 3)
print(lst[i - 1], lst[i])
```

**Output**

```
1 4
```

Note that the time complexity of the second approach is O(n) vs O(logn) of `bisect`. As an alternative you could implement bisect, in the end is just [binary search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-binary-search/).

Comment: Is there any way to do it without importing a module? Sorry for not being specific in the question but I have edited it now.

Comment: @DenseMage See the update